# What was the point of the fake apple grove?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022) Dr. Strange visits Wanda pruning what look like live apple trees.  She first says it’s all real.

Then, not even 2 minutes later, reveals it’s not real, similar to the hex of Wandavision.

What purpose does Wanda have for creating the illusion, lying about it, and then revealing it?  Besides arbitrary plot point, was there a comics reason for it?

Comment: It sets the audience up for a visual matching the reveal of her as the bad guy.

Answer (score 4):

She was attempting to hide her true intentions, but slipped up.

> Wanda: What if you brought America here?
>
> Strange: Here?
>
> W: Yeah. I know what it’s like to be on your own, hunted for abilities
> you never wanted, and I can protect her.
>
> (SUSPENSEFUL MUSIC PLAYS)
>
> W: You never told me her name, did you?

Strange Picked up on it *almost* immediately, and she revealed herself by mistake. She obviously didn't want to attract attention to herself, because then that would create more hassle - having to deal with everyone trying to protect America, instead of just hunting America down on her lonesome. So now she had been discovered, what would the point be of hiding the truth further, as it would only cause more problems. Best reveal herself and her intentions: She only wants one person, there's no need to involve any one else. She knows Strange is all about balance, so maybe he would understand.

And then, as [WakeDemons3 has commented](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/118637/what-was-the-point-of-a-fake-apple-grove#comment208046_118637)

> It sets the audience up for a visual matching the reveal of her as the bad guy.

Comment: I was keying in on the initial part of the conversation where she claims all this is real, and yet that is revealed to be a lie.  What possible motivation does she have for creating another mini-alternate-reality and claiming its real?

The part about getting found out is secondary to me, thats the overall plot of the movie.  But the movie scene itself seems... baffling.   She's created an illusion, Strange comes to visit her, she's expecting him due to Hex reality from Wandavision, and then lies about it from the start.

Comment: Of note, I had considered that the fresh looking apple grove was hiding Wanda using the Darkhold, because it was sucking lifeforce away from the surroundings.  She obviously didnt want people to remark about the dead trees, especially the gaze of Sorcerer Supreme's like Strange or Wong, and used her ability to make them look real.